Snap apps not showing in KDE menu
I just installed Kubuntu 24.04 on a new machine. Everything runs fine but snap apps do not show up in KDE menus (and are not selectable for default applications, which is, in the case of Firefox, very annoying). Is there a way to fix this in a clean manner (not a ln -s-based workaround)?
